# Gitlab CI runs test twice when pushing to master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI config that kinda looks like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge_request
    - master
  script:
    - jest --coverage

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - make deploy
```

I only want the tests to be run when a merge request is opened or if we merge to `master` because I'm only on the free plan on gitlab.com and I'd like to conserve my runner minutes.

If the unit tests ran for every commit we made, we'd always run out of minutes on the 3rd or 4th week.

For the most part, it works. The problem comes from pushing to `master` directly (which can happen every now and then); `test` runs twice and at the same time.

I couldn't find anything on Gitlab docs on how to properly approach this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't see why a direct push to master will run your tests twice except when you have an open merge-request which master as source branch.

You can prevent this from happening by using [workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines). Furthermore you should use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) instead of `only`/`except` as they are not actively developed any more.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - jest --coverage
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - make deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
```

Comment: That was exactly it. There was an open merge request with `master` as the source. It wasn't part of our protocol to do that so never even gave it a thought. So thank you.